# Matrix multiplication

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

please enlighten me with this next issue. I'm trying to multiply 2 Matrices and there's some logical error in my code which I cant identify. Please help. Thank you in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    short int Mtx_A[4][2] = {
        {1,2},
        {3,4},
        {5,6},
        {7,8},
    };

    short int  Mtx_B[2][3] = {
        {5,7,9},
        {11,2,6},
    };

    short int  Mtx_res[4][3] = {0};

    for (short int i = 0;i<4;i++) {         // Mtx_A lines counter
        for (short int j=0;j<2;j++) {       // Mtx_B lines & Mtx_A columns counter
            for (short int k=0;k<3;k++) {   // Mtx_res columns counter
                Mtx_res[i][k] += Mtx_A[i][j] * Mtx_B[j][k];
                cout<< Mtx_res[i][k] <<"*"<<"\t";
            }
            cout<<"o"<<"\n";
        }
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like homework... is it?

Comment: I don't see any direct logical errors, but I do see some unnecessary commas in your matrix definitions. Remove the comma after {7, 8}, and {11, 2, 6}

Comment: In which way does this logical error express itself. Does it compile? Does it run? Does it print unexpected output? What output does it print? What output did you expect?

Comment: Shouldn't you cout the resulting matrix when it's done?

Comment: not homework,I'm trying to learn on my own

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger? Using a debugger will greatly help you understand what the code is doing and will help you identify the problems.

Comment: I'm expecting a 4X3 Matrix,it displays a 8x3,no errors

Comment: @TomKnapen There's nothing wrong with those commas.  I often put them in, for example, if I've a list of elements which will be counted by the compiler to determine the size.  That way, someone who adds an element at the end doesn't have to worry about them, or I can reorder the elements by simply deleting a line and then inserting it elsewhere.  About the only time I won't use them is if the list ends with a sentenal

Comment: Why all the `short int`?  There's no reason not to just use `int` here.

Answer (score 4):

The logic to create your array is correct, but the output is wrong.

The matrix result is two-dimensional, but you are writing three dimensions.

The output must wait until the process is complete.

Answer (score 1):

You're starting to output the resulting matrix when it's not done yet. In fact, you will output each cell of `Mtx_Res` two times, for j = 0 and 1 respectively (hence `8x3` instead of `4x3`, as you said).

I would done the output in a separate loop (after the Mtx_Res construction loops are over):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    cout << Mtx_res[i][j] << "*" << "\t";
  }
  cout << "o" << "\n";
}
```

In fact, I consider this a (usually) useful technique: **separate processing from displaying**. True, sometimes you should do these simultaneously for efficiency sake, but much more often the time won with simplicity will be much more precious both for you - and for your customer. )

Answer (score 1):

You can change your output to emit the cell after all the `j` indices have been processed. The next row in your output proceeds after all the `k` indices have also been processed.

```
            Mtx_res[i][k] += Mtx_A[i][j] * Mtx_B[j][k];
            if (j == 1) {
                cout<< Mtx_res[i][k] <<"*"<<"\t";
                if (k == 2) cout<<"o"<<"\n";
            }
```